# Creating a Dynamic Array from sparse but regular data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data is regular but sparse. As an example, imagine 3 data points in A4, A14 and A24 ("a","b" and "c" respectively). I want to pull these into a table. I need it to be able to adapt to more data points (so there might be 20, might be 2, but always 10 rows apart starting in A4).

Currently, I'm handling this by using an index column (say B1:B3 with the array formula `SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A),1,1,1)`, and then next to that having:

`INDIRECT("R"&4+(B1-1)*10&"C1",FALSE)`

but I have to drag this formula down, and I want it to update dynamically, the way the index column would.

I wanted to make this into a dynamic array by adapting the formula to:

`INDIRECT("R"&4+(B1:B3-1)*10&"C1",FALSE)`

or

`INDIRECT("R"&4+(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A),1,0,1)*10&"C1",FALSE)`

It spills correctly, but both of these return arrays of #VALUE! errors instead of the expected {a,b,c}. Why would this be? Have you got any suggestions for handling this in other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as a cell formula

```
=INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A),1,4,10))
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. This works really well; I hadn't thought to use an array as the row argument of an INDEX() function (I normally either pick a single value or the entire column).

Answer (score 1):

for previous versions of Excel, without Sequence(), this will do

```
=INDEX(B1:B1000,(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,COUNT(B1:B1000)))-1)*10+4)
```

OR put the Distance (ex:10) in D3 / Start in D2 (ex:4) / Total no of Numbers in D1 (ex: D1 = Count(b1:b1000)) and write the formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B1000,(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,$D$1))-1)*$D$3+$D$2)
```

up to you. (enter both as Array Formulas w ctrl+shift+enter)

B1:B1000 will contain up to 100 numbers... so adjust at will and keep small for speed

Comment: Thanks Apostolos, but with the new dynamic array functionality the "ctrl+shift+enter" method is obsolete. I think the answer given by Charles is more elegant (no offsets), although I'm sure yours would work similarly as it's the same in principle (use an array as the row identifier of an INDEX() function).

Comment: Soulus thanks for the comment. 1st thing I stated that my solution is for previous versions of excel, and there still are lots of them out there! I also prefer the non volatile answer with Sequence of Charles, but now people seeing your question get answer no-matter their version. And yes, the (ROW(....) is clearly working similar to the Sequence(). I also used B1:B1000 instead of B:B for speed (at least in older versions of Excel it matters a lot). Cheers